# Attribute and message interchanges when event published to GCP pubsub topic from different source and consume by single receiver

Tags: google-cloud-platform, events, publish, publish-subscribe

Suppose we have 3 application App1, App2, App3, these 3 of each publishes event Which is message and attributes to the GCP pubsub topic. For example App1 publishes message m1 with attribute a1
and App2 publishes message m2 with attribute a2. And these 2 apps publishes thousands of event concurrently. I have single receiver application ReceiverApp. What I can notice is out of thousands event for 5 to 10, ReceiverApp receives message m1 published by App1 with attribute a2 published by App2. Which means when concurrently event published by different application to a topic then message and attributes getting mixed.

Reason, solution ?

Comment: Based on my understanding it seems like the issue is with the publisher. Could you check whether the publisher is publishing the message with attributes correctly. Could you provide more details about your subscription and attributes?

Comment: Each publisher app published their own message and attributes to the topic.

For subscriber written in golang it uses standard library by pubsub, receives message and attributes, subscriber receives messages concurrently having message and attributes.

subError := sub.Receive(ctx, func(ctx context.Context, msg *pubsub.Message) {

if err := proto.Unmarshal(msg.Data, protoMessage); err != nil {
    logger.Error("proto.Unmarshal err: " + err.Error())
    return
   }
 appErr := HandleEmsEntitySubscription_v1(protoMessage.CurrentState, protoMessage.PreviousState, msg.Attributes, ctx)
}

Comment: Has your issue been resolved?

Comment: Yes it is, it were issue with subscriber, in the golang application there were a global variable declared that were just missing the message and attributes running concurrently

Answer (score 0):

@Raju Yadav, As you mentioned in the comment.

> It was an issue with subscriber, in the golang application there were global variables declared that were just missing the message and attributes running concurrently.

Posting the answer as ***community wiki*** for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.